Select multiple items with HTML <select> with a touchscreen
With a HTML <select> in multiple mode, how to enable the selection of multiple items with a touchscreen device?

Drag/drop or swipe cannot be used for selection, it is already used to scroll the scrollbar of the list

Click / tap cannot be used because this is used to select a new single item  (see the UX in Windows File Explorer or Mac Finder)

Double-click / double-tap is already used to open the selected element (e.g. like in a file explorer)


Is there a built-in HTML5 way to do this?



select { width: 10em; height: 12em; }
<select multiple>
  <option>Dog</option>
  <option>Cat</option>
  <option>Hamster</option>
  <option>Parrot</option>
  <option>Spider</option>
  <option>Goldfish</option>
  <option>Elephant</option>
  <option>Mouse</option>
  <option>Bee</option>
  <option>Sheep</option>
  <option>Fox</option>
</select>



Note: this is how it is displayed by default on Android, but I don't want this design because, when we don't click on it, we can't see the selected elements:


I get a popup on my android to select multiple values.

You're right @0stone0. I included it in the question. But I'd like to avoid this design because we don't see which elements are selected (we have to click on it each time we want to see the content).

There are libraries that provide a select that show the selected values on mobile. You could make that native in html5 with some css/js and probably a hidden input.

Would you have an example @0stone0?

It does not seem that there is a native HTML5 way of helping you.
You can use select2 or similar libraries or try this one if it works for you
We could hide a normal select using media queries and have this one select options in it on a mobile


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const dropBtn = document.getElementById('dropbtn');
  const dropdownContent = document.getElementById('myDropdown');

  dropBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    dropdownContent.hidden = !dropdownContent.hidden;
  });

  window.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    const tgt = event.target;
    const parent = tgt.closest('#myDropdown')
    if (!tgt.matches('#dropbtn') && !parent) {
      dropdownContent.hidden = true;
    }  
  });

  dropdownContent.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const tgt = event.target.closest('a');
    if (!tgt) return
    tgt.classList.toggle('active'); // we COULD select a hidden select here

  });
});
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a.active {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
<div class="dropdown">
  <button id="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content" hidden>
    <a href="#">Option 1</a>
    <a href="#">Option 2</a>
    <a href="#">Option 3</a>
  </div>
</div>




Thanks! The problem with this solution is that each time we tap/click on a new item, it gets selected. Which is usually not what we want (see File explorer in Windows or Finder on Mac).

But that is the only way since we cannot ctrl click with out fingers
